# Bash script awk

Tags: unix

I am new to Bash scripting. I am struggling to understand this particular line of code. Please help.

```
old_tag = awk -v search="$new_tag" -F" " '$1==search { a[count] = $2; count++; } END { srand();print a[int(rand()*(count-1))+1] }' $tag_dir/$file
    [ -z "$new_tag" ] && break
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Awk is an own language. We are not replacing your learning capacity. Which part of it do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be incorrect. With `old_tag = awk` the code tries to out the results of the awk command in the var `old_tag`. An assignment of a var should be done without spaces around the `=`, and the command should be enclosed in `$(..)`. It might have been backtics in the original code, these are depreciated and backtics are used for formatting in SO.
Your question would have been easier to answer with an example inputfile, but  try to explain assuming inputlines like

```
apple x1
car a
rotten apple
tree sf
apple x5
car a4
apple x3
```

I switched `old_tag` and `new_tag`, that seems to make more sense.

```
new_tag=$(awk -v search="$old_tag" -F" " '
   $1==search { a[count] = $2; count++; } 
   END { srand(); print a[int(rand()*(count-1))+1] }
   ' $tag_dir/$file)
[ -z "$new_tag" ] && break
```

This cod tries to replace to find a new tag by searching the old tag in `$tag_dir/$file`. When the tag occurs more than once, take one of the lines random.

The code explained in more detail:

```
# assign output to variable new_tag
new_tag=$(..)
# use awk program
awk ..
# Assign the valuo of old_tag to a variable "search" that can be used in awk
-v search="$old_tag"
# Different fields seperated by spaces
-F" "
# The awk programming lines
' .. '
# Check first field of line with the variable search
$1==search { .. } 
# When true, store second field of line in array and increment index
a[count] = $2; count++; 
# Additional comands after processing everything
END {..}
# Print random index from array
srand(); print a[int(rand()*(count-1))+1] 
# Use file as input for awk
$tag_dir/$file
# Stop when no new_tag has been found
[ -z "$new_tag" ] && break
# I would have preferred the syntax 
test -z "${new_tag}" && break
```

With the sample input and `old_tag="apple"`, the code will find the lines with apple as the first word

```
apple x1
apple x5
apple x3
```

The words `x1 x5 x3` are stored in array `a` and randomly one of these 3 is assigned to `new_tag`.